# Polling HTTP endpoint followed by jersey REST WS does not work in Mule 3.5

Tags: java, web-services, mule

I have a requirement where i need to poll a rest service and then proxy the response from this web service on to a REST web service.

I am using Mule 3.5 and my flow looks like the below.
[image]

I get the below exception where the REST service is being invoked

```
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to invoke JerseyResourcesComponent{TestFlow.component.1106552446}. Component that caused exception is: JerseyResourcesComponent{TestFlow.component.1106552446}. Message payload is of type: String
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. null (java.lang.NullPointerException)
  org.mule.module.jersey.JerseyResourcesComponent:192 (null)
2. Failed to invoke JerseyResourcesComponent{TestFlow.component.1106552446}. Component that caused exception is: JerseyResourcesComponent{TestFlow.component.1106552446}. Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.component.ComponentException)
  org.mule.component.AbstractComponent:144 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/component/ComponentException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mule.module.jersey.JerseyResourcesComponent.getBaseUri(JerseyResourcesComponent.java:192)
    at org.mule.module.jersey.JerseyResourcesComponent.doInvoke(JerseyResourcesComponent.java:146)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.invokeInternal(AbstractComponent.java:122)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

After debugging i figured out it is because Mule expects the MuleMessage inbound property for contextPath to be populated however in this case it is null.

In [JerseyResourcesComponent](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mule.modules/mule-module-jersey/3.5.0-bighorn/org/mule/module/jersey/JerseyResourcesComponent.java#JerseyResourcesComponent) line 117 is returned as null and hence line 195 throws a NPE.

**I wanted to know if this kind of requirement/pattern is invalid or is it some kind of limitation in the way Mule is handling its messaging infrastructure ?**

The flow xml just in case you want to inspect it.

```
<flow name="TestFlow" doc:name="TestFlow">

        <poll doc:name="Poll">
            <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="10" timeUnit="SECONDS" startDelay="10"/>
            <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8080" doc:name="Order Generator" method="GET" contentType="application/json" path="order"/>
        </poll>
        <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
        <jersey:resources doc:name="Tax Calculator">
            <component class="org.nthdimenzion.TaxCalculator"/>
        </jersey:resources>

        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

    </flow>
```

PS : The work around i got was to use a java/spring component instead of a REST WS and then call the REST WS from the Java component.

Comment: Its not a valid pattern, to have it behind a poll like that. It should be behind an inbound endpoint to map the uri to the correct resources. If your not doing that you should just use a standard java/spring component for processing the message.